# IFFT of FFT-image results in weird upside-down overlap of original image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, fft

In the following code I have a function which returns an image cropped to a centered circle of a certain radius. Then I perform fourier-tranformation of an image, and reverse fourier-transformation again, to restore the image, which works fine.

Then I have calculated, that a centered circle with radius of 43 of the energy spectrum (excluded here) will yield 99% of the energy of the original image. But when I try to apply my function "imgRadius" to the amplitude-spectrum (the fourier-transformed image), and then perform inverse-fourier-tranformation on that image, I get this weird upside-down overlap of the original image.

```
def imgRadius(img, radius):
    result = np.zeros(img.shape,np.float64)
    centerX = (img.shape[0])/2
    centerY = (img.shape[1])/2
    for m in range(img.shape[0]):
        for n in range(img.shape[1]):
            if math.sqrt((m-centerX)**2+(n-centerY)**2) < radius:
                result[m,n] = img[m,n]
    return result

imgpath = directory+"NorbertWiener.JPG"
img = cv.imread(imgpath, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
norm_image = cv.normalize(img, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv.CV_32F)
amp = (np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(norm_image)))
amp_log = np.log(np.abs(amp))
norm_amp = cv.normalize(amp_log, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv.CV_32F)
restoredAMP = np.abs(np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(amp)))
radamp = imgRadius(norm_amp,43)
rest99 = np.abs(np.fft.ifft2((imgRadius(amp,43))))

plt.subplot(231),plt.imshow(norm_image, "gray", vmin=0, vmax=1),plt.title('Image')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(232),plt.imshow(norm_amp, "gray", vmin=0, vmax=1),plt.title('Amplitude')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(233),plt.imshow(restoredAMP, "gray", vmin=0, vmax=1),plt.title('Restored from amplitude')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(235),plt.imshow(rest99, "gray", vmin=0, vmax=1),plt.title('Restored from r=43')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(234),plt.imshow(radamp, "gray", vmin=0, vmax=1),plt.title('Amplitude r=43')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image: See the resulting subplots here]

Does it somehow have anything to do with the fact that I use absolute values? I don't see how I should be able to plot the image without getting rid of the imaginary parts of the images, but I can see how maybe some information gets lost in the inverse fft.

I just don't get why I don't get problems when performing IFFT on the original amplitude spectrum.

Comment: I think you need to apply your imgRadius() to amp and not norm_amp before restoring it.

Comment: @fmw42 That's what i'm trying to do with the "rest99", which is displayed as the 5th image in the subplots, showing the 'backfolding'

Comment: To recover the image after masking with your radius, you need to mask the result of the FFT and not the log normalized version. The do the IFT on that.  I do not understand why you would want to do the IFT on the log normalized image.

Comment: @fmw42 Maybe the code is a bit confusing, but i am not trying to restore the FFT of the masked log normalized version. That is only used for plotting. The version i have masked and try to restore is simply amp, which is just the result of the FFT. See the variable "rest99"

Comment: Try changing `rest99 = np.abs(np.fft.ifft2((imgRadius(amp,43))))` to `rest99 = np.abs(np.fft.ifft2((imgRadius(amp,43)))).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: @fmw42 I tried applying the changes, but it just results in an all-black image when i try to plot it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem happens here:

```
def imgRadius(img, radius):
    result = np.zeros(img.shape,np.float64)
```

You are creating a real-valued array, and copying over the complex values. Likely either the real component or the magnitude is written to the array. In any case, the complex-valued frequency domain data becomes real-valued. The inverse transform is a symmetric matrix.

To solve the problem, initialize `result` as a complex-valued array.

After this, make sure to use the real component of the inverse transform, not the magnitude, as [Gianluca already suggested in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60477770/7328782).

Comment: Yes, I agree. I did not see that earlier. But I do not know why the OP would do pixel iteration processing to cut out the circle in the dft. My way, using a mask and multiplication, is better as it permits softening of the edges to avoid ringing artifacts.

Comment: This solved the problem! Thanks for the help. By initializing result as a copy of img, and then zeroing the pixels outside the circle, i get the same effect, but with the complex values. And as @fmw42 points out, i could have just used the built in functionality of cv2, and apply some type of low pass filter to the mask in order to avoid blurring. But what Cris Luengo pointed out here is definitely the part where i messed things up the most.

Answer (score 3):

Discarding the imaginary part of the FFT (and also the sign of the real part) is exactly what the problem is leading to the 'backfolding' of the inverted image into itself. The FFT of a function that is symmetric about its origin is real (i.e. imaginary part 0). By discarding the imaginary part, the image has thus been somehow 'symmetrized'.

After performing operations on the complex FFT result in Fourier space, one can take the inverse FFT, and then only plot the real part `np.fft.ifft2((imgRadius(amp,43))).real` of it.

Comment: Okay, i see that plotting the real part is the same as when i apply np.abs to my images, right? I'm still confused about how i can restore the image from amp with out any problems, but when amp is cropped to a circle, it shows the 'backfolding' characteristics.

Comment: @HamDerDolski: If the imaginary part of the IFFT is not nearly zero, then there is an error in the way that the filter is created. It must be exactly centered on the 0 frequency and be perfectly symmetric around that point.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes! I see how that could cause the problem. However, from what i can see should be changed, is only the calculations of centerX and centerY in the imgRadius function. Here i've tried subtracting 1 from each calculation both before and after the division of 2, but this doesnt seem to help. The image still looks weird. Am i missing some clear flaws here?

Comment: @HamDerDolski: I think the center needs to be at `img.shape[0] // 2` (integer division).

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me in Python/OpenCV/Numpy and shows the difference between using a sharp boundary circle and one that has been smoothed by Gaussian blurring in order to mitigate ringing artifacts

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read input and convert to grayscale
img = cv2.imread('lena_gray.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# do dft saving as complex output
dft = np.fft.fft2(img)

# apply shift of origin to center of image
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)

# generate spectrum from magnitude image (for viewing only)
mag = np.abs(dft_shift)
spec = np.log(mag) / 20

# create circle mask
radius = 32
mask = np.zeros_like(img)
cy = mask.shape[0] // 2
cx = mask.shape[1] // 2
cv2.circle(mask, (cx,cy), radius, (255,255,255), -1)[0]

# blur the mask
mask2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (19,19), 0)

# apply mask to dft_shift
dft_shift_masked = np.multiply(dft_shift,mask) / 255
dft_shift_masked2 = np.multiply(dft_shift,mask2) / 255


# shift origin from center to upper left corner
back_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(dft_shift)
back_ishift_masked = np.fft.ifftshift(dft_shift_masked)
back_ishift_masked2 = np.fft.ifftshift(dft_shift_masked2)


# do idft saving as complex output
img_back = np.fft.ifft2(back_ishift)
img_filtered = np.fft.ifft2(back_ishift_masked)
img_filtered2 = np.fft.ifft2(back_ishift_masked2)

# combine complex components to form original image again
img_back = np.abs(img_back).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
img_filtered = np.abs(img_filtered).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
img_filtered2 = np.abs(img_filtered2).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)


cv2.imshow("ORIGINAL", img)
cv2.imshow("SPECTRUM", spec)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("MASK2", mask2)
cv2.imshow("ORIGINAL DFT/IFT ROUND TRIP", img_back)
cv2.imshow("FILTERED DFT/IFT ROUND TRIP", img_filtered)
cv2.imshow("FILTERED2 DFT/IFT ROUND TRIP", img_filtered2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("lena_dft_numpy_mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("lena_dft_numpy_mask_blurred.png", mask2)
cv2.imwrite("lena_dft_numpy_roundtrip.png", img_back)
cv2.imwrite("lena_dft_numpy_lowpass_filtered1.png", img_filtered)
cv2.imwrite("lena_dft_numpy_lowpass_filtered2.png", img_filtered2)
```

Sharp Mask:

[image]

Blurred Mask:

[image]

Simple Round Trip:

[image]

Low Pass Filtered Result from sharp mask (ringing obvious):

[image]

Low Pass Filtered Result from blurred mask (ringing mitigated):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm fairly new to opencv, so i didn't know it had the circle mask functionality built in. I also see how the low-pass filtering of the mask can help minimize ringing, thanks for pointing that out. As @Cris Luengo pointed out, i messed up when initializing the result image in my own circle-mask function "imgRadius", and fixing that solved the 'backfolding' issue.