# How to extract out the horizontal and vertical strips using OpenCV?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, fft

I have two FFT images and I would like to extract out the FFT structure or strips vertically and hotrizontally (excluding the origin area) using Opencv.

I was trying with this image
[image]

here is the second image
[image]

Here is the piece of code i was trying

```
image = cv2.imread('fft_img.png', 0)
gray_filtered = cv2.inRange(image, 130, 155)
ret, th1 = cv2.threshold(image, 150, 160, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
adaptive_threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
cv2.imshow('Original Image', image)
cv2.imshow('In range threshold Image', gray_filtered)
cv2.imshow('Adaptive Thresholded Image', adaptive_threshold)
```

[image]

Comment: Starting from a JPG you are unlikely to get much joy since that has already been  compressed with quantisation losses occurring in the x-y domain. Store the FFT in a lossless format! The stripes in your original images are the two bright lines in the Fourier domain that cross at the origin. I'm guessing it is those that you want to eliminate (ie set to zero or average of nearest neighbours) and that everything else off axis is a genuine part of your target image. It would help to see the original images as well. Very few people can instinctively interpret Fourier transform data.

Comment: Hey @martin brown am basically trying to detect the strips not eliminating them that is why i was trying thresholding techniques to extract them out because strips has bright values compare to the background. I am trying with PNG as well and updated in the question

Comment: locally adaptive threshold is a sensible approach. vary the parameters.

Comment: It might still be easier to eliminate them in Fourier space and then subtract the resulting inverse transformed image from your original to isolate the stripes. It wasn't clear from your question that the horizontal and vertical stripes were the thing that you wanted to preserve! They looked like artefacts to me. If you know which bits of the data really matter to you in the Fourier domain then mask off all the stuff you don't want with a filter. eg. try a Gaussian exp(-ax^2)*exp(-ay^2) centred on the axes.

Comment: @MartinBrown Yes the aim is to remove those artefact and these strips are the representation of those artifact in FFT. The idea was to extract those strips and mask them in FFT and then do the inverse FFT.

Comment: I found similar approach here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60480549/22776587  but this could not answer my basic question